# git pull not recognising IPv4 option

Tags: git

According to the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#git-pull--4), `git pull` can take `-4` or `--ipv4` option. But, whenever I do `git pull origin master -4` or `git pull -4 origin master`, it fails with the error `` error: unknown switch `4' ``. `-4` option works with `git push` though. I have the latest version 2.15.1 of git. Using Ubuntu 14.04

With `--ipv4` error becomes `` error: unknown option `ipv4' ``

How can I use git pull with IPv4 option?

PS: I cannot use `git pull origin master` because it fails with the error `Failed to connect to bitbucket.org port 443: Network is unreachable` and according to BitBucket, workaround is to use `-4`

Comment: I recommend avoiding `git pull`: break it up into the two separate commands it runs for you. Just run each of those two commands yourself. It makes Git make more sense, and in this case, it also sidesteps the bug that larsks mentions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a bug in git.  It was fixed in commit [c2b6135a1b52a567c92286bb1d3345b6cb0db584](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c2b6135a1b52a567c92286bb1d3345b6cb0db584), which should show up in 2.16.0 when it is released.

Comment: Meanwhile Samkit can use `git fetch` directly: `git fetch -4 origin master && git merge origin/master`